# Connected devices are not showing to run the project after updating the android studio to 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

i recently updated my android studio after update connected devices are not showing to run the project.(developer options and usb debugging mode all are fine of device side). how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart adb using terminal, Connect your device and type

"adb devices" command

it will restart adb and ask for the permission in phone